# How to add global warning rule suppression in StyleCop.Settings file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration, warnings, stylecop, suppress-warnings

I am getting 5k+ StyleCop warnings of different flavours. I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express edition, so there is no menu option to go to `StyleCop` settings or do suppressions for warnings from within Visual Studio. Only option left  is to edit `StyleCop.Settings` file which I am attempting to do atm, StyleCop version I am using is 4.7.

My StyleCop.Settings file looks like this:

```
<StyleCopSettings Version="4.3">
  <GlobalSettings>
    <CollectionProperty Name="DeprecatedWords">
      <Value>preprocessor,pre-processor</Value>
      <Value>shortlived,short-lived</Value>
    </CollectionProperty>
  </GlobalSettings>
  <Parsers>
    <Parser ParserId="StyleCop.CSharp.CsParser">
      <ParserSettings>
        <CollectionProperty Name="GeneratedFileFilters">
          <Value>\.g\.cs$</Value>
          <Value>\.generated\.cs$</Value>
          <Value>\.g\.i\.cs$</Value>
        </CollectionProperty>
      </ParserSettings>
    </Parser>
  </Parsers>
  <Analyzers>
    <Analyzer AnalyzerId="StyleCop.CSharp.NamingRules">
      <AnalyzerSettings>
        <CollectionProperty Name="Hungarian">
          <Value>as</Value>
          <Value>do</Value>
          <Value>id</Value>
          <Value>if</Value>
          <Value>in</Value>
          <Value>is</Value>
          <Value>my</Value>
          <Value>no</Value>
          <Value>on</Value>
          <Value>to</Value>
          <Value>ui</Value>
        </CollectionProperty>
      </AnalyzerSettings>
    </Analyzer>
  </Analyzers>
</StyleCopSettings>
```

**How would I need to edit settings file to suppress all warnings that are within `CSharp.Ordering` and `CSharp.Documentation`, or do it code by code (`SA1202, SA1600`)?** I don't mind any solution.

```
SA1202 : CSharp.Ordering : All private methods must be placed after all public methods.     
SA1600 : CSharp.Documentation : The method must have a documentation header.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved myself, in your StyleCop installation folder, same folder where `StyleCop.Settings` file is (in my case its `C:\Program Files\StyleCop 4.7`).
There should be a file named `StyleCopSettingsEditor.exe`. Drag and drop `StyleCop.Settings` onto `StyleCopSettingsEditor.exe` this should launch the application and open the window shown in screenshot below.

[image]

You can edit settings by group or by specific code.

For those who do not have ability to use editor for whatever reason, XML below shows how `StyleCop.Settings` file looks after editing.

```
<StyleCopSettings Version="105">
  <GlobalSettings>
    <CollectionProperty Name="DeprecatedWords">
      <Value>preprocessor,pre-processor</Value>
      <Value>shortlived,short-lived</Value>
    </CollectionProperty>
  </GlobalSettings>
  <Parsers>
    <Parser ParserId="StyleCop.CSharp.CsParser">
      <ParserSettings>
        <CollectionProperty Name="GeneratedFileFilters">
          <Value>\.g\.cs$</Value>
          <Value>\.generated\.cs$</Value>
          <Value>\.g\.i\.cs$</Value>
        </CollectionProperty>
      </ParserSettings>
    </Parser>
  </Parsers>
  <Analyzers>
    <Analyzer AnalyzerId="StyleCop.CSharp.NamingRules">
      <AnalyzerSettings>
        <CollectionProperty Name="Hungarian">
          <Value>as</Value>
          <Value>do</Value>
          <Value>id</Value>
          <Value>if</Value>
          <Value>in</Value>
          <Value>is</Value>
          <Value>my</Value>
          <Value>no</Value>
          <Value>on</Value>
          <Value>to</Value>
          <Value>ui</Value>
        </CollectionProperty>
      </AnalyzerSettings>
    </Analyzer>
    <Analyzer AnalyzerId="StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules">
      <Rules>
        <Rule Name="ElementsMustBeDocumented">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="PartialElementsMustBeDocumented">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="EnumerationItemsMustBeDocumented">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="DocumentationMustContainValidXml">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementDocumentationMustHaveSummary">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="PartialElementDocumentationMustHaveSummary">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementDocumentationMustHaveSummaryText">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="PartialElementDocumentationMustHaveSummaryText">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementDocumentationMustNotHaveDefaultSummary">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementParametersMustBeDocumented">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementParameterDocumentationMustMatchElementParameters">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementParameterDocumentationMustDeclareParameterName">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementParameterDocumentationMustHaveText">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementReturnValueMustBeDocumented">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementReturnValueDocumentationMustHaveText">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="VoidReturnValueMustNotBeDocumented">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="GenericTypeParametersMustBeDocumented">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="GenericTypeParametersMustBeDocumentedPartialClass">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="GenericTypeParameterDocumentationMustMatchTypeParameters">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="GenericTypeParameterDocumentationMustDeclareParameterName">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="GenericTypeParameterDocumentationMustHaveText">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="PropertySummaryDocumentationMustMatchAccessors">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="PropertySummaryDocumentationMustOmitSetAccessorWithRestrictedAccess">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementDocumentationMustNotBeCopiedAndPasted">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="SingleLineCommentsMustNotUseDocumentationStyleSlashes">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="DocumentationTextMustNotBeEmpty">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="DocumentationTextMustContainWhitespace">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="DocumentationMustMeetCharacterPercentage">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ConstructorSummaryDocumentationMustBeginWithStandardText">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="DestructorSummaryDocumentationMustBeginWithStandardText">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="DocumentationHeadersMustNotContainBlankLines">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="IncludedDocumentationXPathDoesNotExist">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="IncludeNodeDoesNotContainValidFileAndPath">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="InheritDocMustBeUsedWithInheritingClass">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementDocumentationMustBeSpelledCorrectly">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="FileMustHaveHeader">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="FileHeaderMustShowCopyright">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="FileHeaderMustHaveCopyrightText">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="FileHeaderMustContainFileName">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="FileHeaderFileNameDocumentationMustMatchFileName">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="FileHeaderMustHaveValidCompanyText">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="FileHeaderFileNameDocumentationMustMatchTypeName">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
      </Rules>
      <AnalyzerSettings />
    </Analyzer>
    <Analyzer AnalyzerId="StyleCop.CSharp.OrderingRules">
      <Rules>
        <Rule Name="UsingDirectivesMustBePlacedWithinNamespace">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementsMustAppearInTheCorrectOrder">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ElementsMustBeOrderedByAccess">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ConstantsMustAppearBeforeFields">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="StaticElementsMustAppearBeforeInstanceElements">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="DeclarationKeywordsMustFollowOrder">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="ProtectedMustComeBeforeInternal">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="PropertyAccessorsMustFollowOrder">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="EventAccessorsMustFollowOrder">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="StaticReadonlyElementsMustAppearBeforeStaticNonReadonlyElements">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Name="InstanceReadonlyElementsMustAppearBeforeInstanceNonReadonlyElements">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
      </Rules>
      <AnalyzerSettings />
    </Analyzer>
  </Analyzers>
</StyleCopSettings>
```